# Flutter with Riverpod and GoRouter : ConsumerWidget doesn't detect StateProvider update

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, gorouter

I'm trying to manage routes in my application using goRouter and Riverpod, and everything is working perfectly except for the navBar. I have a state provider that helps me display which item is currently being shown by the router (just an integer). I'm trying to modify this state in my goRouter provider when calling the redirect function but without success.

Here's the problem: when I call "ref.read(navBarIndexProvider.notifier).state = myTabId;" in my redirect function, the state change is not detected in BottomNavBarItem (it is detected in goRouterProvider). Conversely, when I call "ref.read(navBarIndexProvider.notifier).state = myIntValue" from my BottomNavBarItem widget, the state change is not detected in goRouterProvider. I have the feeling that there are two instances of my navBarIndexProvider, but I'm not sure if that's possible and, if it is, I wonder why.

I'm using
Flutter 3.10.5
dart Dart 3.0.5
flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.10
go_router: ^9.0.3

In short, I am completely lost, and if anyone has an idea, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

My index provider :

```
final navBarIndexProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) {
  return 0;
});
```

My navbar item

```
class BottomNavBarItem extends ConsumerWidget {
  const BottomNavBarItem({required this.icon, required this.path, required this.index, super.key});

  final IconData icon;
  final String path;
  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    int navBarIndexState = ref.watch(navBarIndexProvider);

    void onItemTapped() {
      //ref.read(navBarIndexProvider.notifier).state = index;
      context.go(path);
    }

    return
      IconButton(
        enableFeedback: false,
        onPressed: () => onItemTapped(),
        icon: Icon(
          icon,
          color: navBarIndexState == index ? AppColors.primaryDarkest : Colors.white,
          size: 30,
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Here my GoRouterProvider

```
final goRouterProvider = Provider<GoRouter>((ref) {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> shellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();


  String? redirect(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    final String destination = state.location;

    print('Before update : ${ref.read(navBarIndexProvider)}');
    print(destination);


    if (destination == '/') {
      ref.read(navBarIndexProvider.notifier).state = 0;
    }
    if (destination == '/page1') {
      ref.read(navBarIndexProvider.notifier).state = 1;
    }
    if (destination == '/page2') {
      ref.read(navBarIndexProvider.notifier).state = 2;
    }
    print('After udpdate : ${ref.read(navBarIndexProvider)}');

    return null;
  }

  return GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/',
    navigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
    redirect: redirect,
    routes: [
      ShellRoute(
        navigatorKey: shellNavigatorKey,
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, Widget child) {
          return NoTransitionPage(
            child: Scaffold(
              extendBody: true,
              body: child,
              bottomNavigationBar: const MyBottomNavBar(),
            ),
          );
        },
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: '/',
            parentNavigatorKey: shellNavigatorKey,
            pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(child: HomePage()),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: '/page1',
            parentNavigatorKey: shellNavigatorKey,
            pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(child: SwipePage()),
          ),
          //...
          ],),
    ],
  );
});
```

My main function

```
Future<void> main() async {

  //...

  //Riverpods
  final container = ProviderContainer();

  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      parent: container,
      child:
          BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => PaymentBloc(),
        child: p.MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            p.ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (_) => AuthProvider(),
            ),
          ],
          child: const MyApp(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I call my app router like this

```
class MyApp extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  ConsumerState<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends ConsumerState<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final router = ref.watch(goRouterProvider);

    return MaterialApp.router(

        //Router
        routerConfig: router);
  }
}
```

Comment: I would just approach this problem differently. Add a parameter indicating chosen tab to your `BottomNavBarItem` widget, calculate this parameter inside `pageBuilder` function based on `state.location` and provide it down to `BottomNavBarItem`. Overall I feel like using a separate StateProvider is unnecessary here since it's just used in one place and it kinda duplicates the idea of "location" that you already have from GoRouter. Let me know if this helps

Comment: Your idea solved my problem: I removed my NavBarIndexProvider, the logic inside the redirect function, and inside the BottomNavBarItem widget. I simply used `GoRouterState.of(context).uri.toString()` inside the BottomNavBarItem to retrieve the current location, and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot! (I'm still curious why the previous code didn't work.)

Comment: Nice! Would be great if you could upvote my comment and make an answer to your question with the solution that worked. I'm also not sure about the exact reason for that bug

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find the upvote button, I think it's because I don't have enough reputation :/